# Вектор с шаблонируемым классом

Tags: c++, vector

Вот уж не знаю то ли вопрос такой глупый, то ли я действительно такой большой оригинал, но найти какую-то информацию по своему вопросу я не смог. А вопрос состоит в следующем: можно ли использовать vector для хранения экземпляров класса, использующего шаблоны?

То есть, могу ли я каким-то образом использовать вектор, например, такого типа?

```
vector<SomeClass<int>> v;
```

На первый взгляд, никаких конфликтов с типами быть не должно. Но моя IDE'ха выдаёт мне вот такое вот сообщение:

> Cannot generate template specialization from 'vector(T ,Alocator)'

PS: Работаю с древнейшим компилятором 2000ого года (Borland C++ Builder 5), без возможности его изменить, так что использовать какие-то совсем уж новые прибамбасы у меня может и не получиться.

Comment: 2000 год? Тут тогда речь идёт не о новых прибамбасах, а о совершенно базовых вещах. Немедленно любой ценой убегайте от этого компилятора.

Comment: Чтобы снять вопросы :), попробуйте объявить переменную типа `vector<vector<int> >`. Если пройдет - значит, что-то не так просто у вас, как написано... Если нет - то это неправильные пчелы... в смысле, неправильный компилятор...

Comment: @VladD увы, но как и сказал, иногда инструмент выбирать не приходится.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Шаблонный класс, у которого указаны (специфицированы) конкретные "значения"-аргументы для всех шаблонных параметров, является обычным классом и может использоваться везде, где может использоваться любой обычный (нешаблонный) класс. Ничего особенного тут нет.

Если приведенное вами объявление следует воспринимать буквально, то в вашем случае очевидной ошибкой являются лишь идущие подряд закрывающие треугольные скобки `>>`. В "старых" версиях спецификации языка они рассматривались парсером как неделимая лексема `>>`, а не как две закрывающие треугольные скобки. Поэтому при использовании с вложенными шаблонами между ними следовало ставить пробел

```
vector<SomeClass<int> > v;
```

В современных версиях языка С++ (начиная с С++11) эта особенность синтаксиса устранена.

В вашем случае - компилятор 2000 года - разумеется, следует обязательно ставить этот пробел.

В остальном ничего необычного в вашем объявлении нет, если вы не скрываете от нас что-то важное.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Проблема действительно была в этом.